# wordpress paginate_links url

Tags: php, wordpress

my code looks like this:

```
paginate_links( 
  array(
   'next_text' => __('>'), 
   'prev_text' => __('<'), 
   'base' => @add_query_arg('page', '%#%'), 
   'format' => '?page=%#%&a='.$a, 
   'total' => ceil($count/$per_page), 
   'current' => $page)
)
```

Everything works perfectly but if I click on for example second page my url goes to `www.domain.com/something/2/?a=5` instead of `www.domain.com/something/?page=2&a=5`

Is it possible to change it into `www.domain.com/something/?page=2&a=5`?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you use permalinks :

> format (string) (optional) Used for Pagination structure. The default
>   value is '?page=%#%', If using pretty permalinks this would be
>   '/page/%#%', where the '%#%' is replaced by the page number. Default:
>   '?page=%#%'

Just rename the var page into something else